# How to configure spring datasource programmatically in web based app which uses JdbcTemplate and SpringDaoSupport?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, datasource, jdbctemplate

I am trying to create a spring web app which is using JdbcTemplate and SpringDaoSupport. When I am defining the datasource bean through dispatcher-servlet xml it's working fine. i.e.

```
<bean id="dataSource" 
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"/>
  <property name="username" value="system"/>
  <property name="password" value="password1$"/>
</bean>
```

But whenever I'm tryinh to configure the dataSource bean through program, it getting exception.The configuration is as follows:

**In code:**

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        driverManagerDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE");
        driverManagerDataSource.setUsername("username");
        driverManagerDataSource.setPassword("password");
        return driverManagerDataSource;
    }   
}
```

**In XML:**

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.example.AppConfig" />
```

Comment: Please add your exception stack trace.

Comment: What is this AppConfig with `dataSource` as an id? It looks like you're mixing two concepts here. Your configuration class does not need to have an id as this is just a container of bean configuration. In your java code, the bean will be exposed with the name of the method by default (which is `dataSource` as you would expect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `dispatcher-servlet.xml` you need to make sure you have either:

```
<context:annotation-config/>

<bean class="com.example.AppConfig" />
```

or

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example"/>
```

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: com.example.AppConfig;Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/objectweb/asm/Type

Comment: :-) the second exception is obvious, of course. You were asked to provide the stack trace and my answer was based only on what you have provided in the question, where no stack trace or exception was specified :-).